# Pad day and time in MomentJS without extra logic

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date formatted in Moment.JS but when I call

```
currentDay.month()
//Or
currentDay.date()
```

I get a 1 digit number (for example Jan 1st would be 0 for month and 1 for day). I need to get this with a leading 0 for date and month if less than 10. I can do this with something like...

```
currentDay.date() >= 10 ? currentDay.date() : '0'+currentDay.date()
```

But I was looking for something a bit nicer. Can I do this easily with MomentJS? I don't see anything in docs.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question. Why is it getting downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, eg for the month, with

```
moment().format('MM')
```